# Gitlab Runner Install Setting Tags

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I need to be able to set the tags for a runner during the registration process, or right afterwards via the CLI in an Amazon Linux instance. I haven't been able to find any documentation for doing so and have attempted several potential methods that have all failed. Does anyone know how adding tags can be accomplished from the CLI, not in the admin/runners UI?

Ideally, we would also like to be able to disable 'Run untagged jobs' for the runner so that the runners will only pick up similarly tagged jobs.